# Installing the chocolatey package manager with another application

Tags: windows, cmd, chocolatey

Generally, I wanted to use the tool as shown in the video: https://youtu.be/tPRv-ATUBe4. But when I run it, a strange thing happens. This chocolatey package manager installs for me. With this command, which I run the program in this video, I also install the chocolatey package manager. I've removed this manager before, and even environment variables, but still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Not that strange at all, if you have a look at the [source](https://github.com/ChrisTitusTech/winutil/blob/5c8c2f34425eef95c6474ec391e9c9cd6cd52304/winutil.ps1#L20), as the tool installs chocolatey if it's not installed.